# How can I convert a PHLivePhoto to UIImage?

Tags: swift, photokit

In my app I have a section of code where I need to account for a PHLivePhoto type object and convert this to a UIImage. I believe it has to do with a `PHAsset`, `PHAssetResource`, or `PHImageManager` but unclear how to perform the conversion. What's a good approach on how to convert from PHLivePhoto -> UIImage? Thanks for the help!

```
if let livePhoto = object as? PHLivePhoto {
    let livePhotoResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: livePhoto)
    print("\(livePhotoResources)")
    
    // imageBucket is of type UIImage[]
    // livePhoto is of type PHLivePhoto but I don't know how to convert this to type PHAsset
    viewModel.imageBucket.append(convertImageAsset(asset: **WHAT_DO_I_INSERT_HERE**))
}
```

...

```
func convertImageAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var tmpImage = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true
            manager.requestImage(
                for: asset,
                   targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight),
                   contentMode: .aspectFit,
                   options: option,
                   resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                       tmpImage = result!
                   })
            return tmpImage
        }
```

results in:

```
[<PHAssetResource: 0x28225cdc0> {
    type: photo
    uti: public.heic
    filename: IMG_5442.heic
    asset: (null)
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2FB56305-7600-4A8E-9C67-A71B4A4A9607/tmp/live-photo-bundle/75FD3D97-F13E-4F79-A6E9-F0743D443FDD.pvt/IMG_5442.HEIC
    width: 0
    height: 0
    fileSize: 0
    analysisType: unavailable
    cplResourceType: Unknown
    isCurrent: NO
    isInCloud: NO
}, <PHAssetResource: 0x28226bc00> {
    type: video_cmpl
    uti: com.apple.quicktime-movie
    filename: IMG_5442.mov
    asset: (null)
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2FB56305-7600-4A8E-9C67-A71B4A4A9607/tmp/live-photo-bundle/75FD3D97-F13E-4F79-A6E9-F0743D443FDD.pvt/IMG_5442.MOV
    width: 0
    height: 0
    fileSize: 0
    analysisType: unavailable
    cplResourceType: Unknown
    isCurrent: NO
    isInCloud: NO
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `PHAsset` to fetch the asset, then request image data from `PHImageManager.default()`

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
    
    guard let assetIdentifier = results.first?.assetIdentifier  else {
        return
    }
    
    if let phAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [assetIdentifier], options: nil).firstObject {
        PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: phAsset, options: nil) { [weak self] data, _, _, _ in
            if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                self?.viewModel.imageBucket.append(image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get assetIdentifier, you need to create `PHPickerConfiguration` object using the shared photo library. Creating a configuration without a photo library provides only asset data, and doesn't include asset identifiers.

```
var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
// Set the filter type according to the user’s selection. .images is a filter to display images, including Live Photos.
configuration.filter = .images
// Set the mode to avoid transcoding, if possible, if your app supports arbitrary image/video encodings.
configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
// Set the selection limit.
configuration.selectionLimit = 1
    
let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
picker.delegate = self
present(picker, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but you did not explain how you're getting [assetIdentifier] here. Please do elaborate more in your response. thank you!

Comment: Hi @ninu I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Hey @Bobby your code makes sense in theory. However, when the picker shows up in my app and I select a Live Photo then click "Add" in the top right corner, the picker(picker: results:) function executes the guard let assetIdentifier and the return fires b/c results.first?assetIdentifier is nil. Any ideas?

Comment: I even added `for result in results { print("The asset identifier is: \(String(describing: result.assetIdentifier))")}` before your guard statement and this always shows **nil** no matter which Live Photo is chosen.

Comment: Please check how you initialize your picker configuration, it should be like that: `var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())` 
`PHPickerConfiguration` object should be created using the shared photo library. Creating a configuration without a photo library provides only asset data, and doesn't include asset identifiers.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I was using the boilerplate WWDC2020 demo code and they had initialized with PHPickerConfiguration() without the parameter of photoLibrary: .shared() and adding it solved the problem! How did you know to add the .shared() because that was not obvious from the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerconfiguration/3616114-init

Comment: Yeah, that's really not obvious. Here is where I read about it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/selecting_photos_and_videos_in_ios

Answer (score 7):

The problem with the accepted answer is that fetching a `PHAsset` will require photo library access, and one of the main advantages of `PHPickerViewController` is being able to get the photos without asking for permissions, and completely avoiding all the related edge cases.

So another way of getting a live photo's image would be:

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    for result in results {
        // Live photos
        if result.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: PHLivePhoto.self) {
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: PHLivePhoto.self, completionHandler: { livePhoto, error in
                let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: livePhoto as! PHLivePhoto)
                let photo = resources.first(where: { $0.type == .photo })!
                let imageData = NSMutableData()
                
                PHAssetResourceManager.default().requestData(for: photo, options: nil, dataReceivedHandler: { data in
                    imageData.append(data)
                }, completionHandler: { error in
                    _ = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)!
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```